# Create an Azure Keyvault with Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to create a keyvault with Python by running the code from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-python-manage):

```
import os
import json
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient
from haikunator import Haikunator

haikunator = Haikunator()

WEST_US = "westus"
GROUP_NAME = "azure-sample-group"
KV_NAME = haikunator.haikunate()
# The object ID of the User or Application for access policies. Find this number in the portal
OBJECT_ID = "401e9294-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"

# Manage resources and resource groups - create, update and delete a resource group,
# deploy a solution into a resource group, export an ARM template. Create, read, update
# and delete a resource
#
# This script expects that the following environment vars are set:
#
# AZURE_TENANT_ID: with your Azure Active Directory tenant id or domain
# AZURE_CLIENT_ID: with your Azure Active Directory Application Client ID
# AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: with your Azure Active Directory Application Secret
# AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: with your Azure Subscription Id
#


def run_example():
    """Resource Group management example."""
    #
    # Create the Resource Manager Client with an Application (service principal) token provider
    #
    subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]

    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"],
        secret=os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
        tenant=os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"],
    )
    kv_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    # You MIGHT need to add KeyVault as a valid provider for these credentials
    # If so, this operation has to be done only once for each credentials
    resource_client.providers.register("Microsoft.KeyVault")

    # Create Resource group
    print("\nCreate Resource Group")
    resource_group_params = {"location": WEST_US}
    print_item(
        resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME, resource_group_params
        )
    )

    # Create a vault
    print("\nCreate a vault")
    vault = kv_client.vaults.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        KV_NAME,
        {
            "location": WEST_US,
            "properties": {
                "sku": {"name": "standard"},
                "tenant_id": os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"],
                "access_policies": [
                    {
                        "tenant_id": os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"],
                        "object_id": OBJECT_ID,
                        "permissions": {"keys": ["all"], "secrets": ["all"]},
                    }
                ],
            },
        },
    )
    print_item(vault)

    # List the Key vaults
    print("\nList KeyVault")
    for vault in kv_client.vaults.list():
        print_item(vault)

    # Delete Resource group and everything in it
    print("\nDelete Resource Group")
    delete_async_operation = resource_client.resource_groups.delete(GROUP_NAME)
    delete_async_operation.wait()
    print("\nDeleted: {}".format(GROUP_NAME))


def print_item(group):
    """Print an instance."""
    print("\tName: {}".format(group.name))
    print("\tId: {}".format(group.id))
    print("\tLocation: {}".format(group.location))
    print("\tTags: {}".format(group.tags))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_example()
```

After receiving comments, I assigned the `Contribute`role to the service principal.

My only modification to the code was substituting the object id with the one from my service principal (see image below):

[image]

I'm receiving following error:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Accepted @sridev's answer because I solved the issue by running the sample code which was linked in the comments

Here's my working code, based on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/tree/main/samples/keyvault), assuming that the Azure environment variables are set properly:

```
import os

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient


def main():
    TENANT_ID = os.environ.get("AZURE_TENANT_ID", None)
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID = os.environ.get("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID", None)
    GROUP_NAME = "resource_group_name"
    VAULT = "vault_name"
    LOCATION = "azure_location_eg_westus"
    OBJECT_ID = "service_principal_object_id"

    # Create client
    # Other authentication approaches: https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
    keyvault_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )

    # Create resource group
    resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, {"location": LOCATION})

    # Create vault
    vault = keyvault_client.vaults.begin_create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VAULT,
        {
            "location": LOCATION,
            "properties": {
                "tenant_id": TENANT_ID,
                "sku": {"family": "A", "name": "standard"},
                "access_policies": [
                    {
                        "tenant_id": TENANT_ID,
                        "object_id": OBJECT_ID,
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "encrypt",
                                "decrypt",
                                "wrapKey",
                                "unwrapKey",
                                "sign",
                                "verify",
                                "get",
                                "list",
                                "create",
                                "update",
                                "import",
                                "delete",
                                "backup",
                                "restore",
                                "recover",
                                "purge",
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "get",
                                "list",
                                "set",
                                "delete",
                                "backup",
                                "restore",
                                "recover",
                                "purge",
                            ],
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "enabled_for_deployment": True,
                "enabled_for_disk_encryption": True,
                "enabled_for_template_deployment": True,
            },
        },
    ).result()
    print("Create vault:\n{}".format(vault))

    # Get vault
    vault = keyvault_client.vaults.get(GROUP_NAME, VAULT)
    print("Get vault:\n{}".format(vault))

    # Update vault
    vault = keyvault_client.vaults.update(
        GROUP_NAME, VAULT, {"tags": {"category": "Marketing"}}
    )
    print("Update vault:\n{}".format(vault))

    # Delete vault
    keyvault_client.vaults.delete(GROUP_NAME, VAULT)
    print("Delete vault.\n")

    # Purge a deleted vault
    keyvault_client.vaults.begin_purge_deleted(VAULT, LOCATION).result()
    print("Purge a deleted vault.\n")

    # Delete Group
    resource_client.resource_groups.begin_delete(GROUP_NAME).result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually occurs if your service principal don't have sufficient **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one web application named `SriApp` in my Azure AD tenant like below:

[image]

When I ran the below code without assigning any **RBAC role** to above servie principal, I got **same error** as below:

```py
import os
import json
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient
from haikunator import Haikunator

haikunator = Haikunator()

WEST_US = 'Germany West Central'
GROUP_NAME = 'azure-sample-resources'
KV_NAME = haikunator.haikunate()
# The object ID of the User or Application for access policies. Find this number in the portal
OBJECT_ID = 'bfc7171d-8c25-4b41-9764-xxxxxxxxxxx'

def run_example():
    """Resource Group management example."""
    #
    # Create the Resource Manager Client with an Application (service principal) token provider
    #
    subscription_id = '124c97c3-58a7-4eb5-ac50-xxxxxxxxxx'

    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id='794cb163-ca1c-4fec-b7df-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        tenant='6c3f1c39-b84c-4188-b49f-xxxxxxxxx'
    )
    kv_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    # You MIGHT need to add KeyVault as a valid provider for these credentials
    # If so, this operation has to be done only once for each credentials
    resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.KeyVault')

    # Create Resource group
    print('\nCreate Resource Group')
    resource_group_params = {'location': WEST_US}
    print_item(resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME, resource_group_params))

    # Create a vault
    print('\nCreate a vault')
    vault = kv_client.vaults.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        KV_NAME,
        {
            'location': WEST_US,
            'properties': {
                'sku': {
                    'name': 'standard'
                },
                'tenant_id': '6c3f1c39-b84c-4188-b49f-xxxxxxxxx',
                'access_policies': [{
                    'tenant_id': '6c3f1c39-b84c-4188-b49f-xxxxxxxx',
                    'object_id': OBJECT_ID,
                    'permissions': {
                        'keys': ['all'],
                        'secrets': ['all']
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    )
    print_item(vault)

    # List the Key vaults
    print('\nList KeyVault')
    for vault in kv_client.vaults.list():
        print_item(vault)

    # Delete Resource group and everything in it
    # print('\nDelete Resource Group')
    # delete_async_operation = resource_client.resource_groups.delete(GROUP_NAME)
    # delete_async_operation.wait()
    # print("\nDeleted: {}".format(GROUP_NAME))


def print_item(group):
    """Print an instance."""
    print("\tName: {}".format(group.name))
    print("\tId: {}".format(group.id))
    print("\tLocation: {}".format(group.location))
    print("\tTags: {}".format(group.tags))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_example()
```

**Response**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to assign **`Contributor`** role to the service principal under your subscription like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Contributor***

[image]

After assigning the role, I ran the code again and got **response** successfully like below:

```py
import os
import json
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient
from haikunator import Haikunator

haikunator = Haikunator()

WEST_US = 'Germany West Central'
GROUP_NAME = 'azure-sample-resources'
KV_NAME = haikunator.haikunate()
# The object ID of the User or Application for access policies. Find this number in the portal
OBJECT_ID = 'bfc7171d-8c25-4b41-9764-xxxxxxxxxxx'

def run_example():
    """Resource Group management example."""
    #
    # Create the Resource Manager Client with an Application (service principal) token provider
    #
    subscription_id = '124c97c3-58a7-4eb5-ac50-xxxxxxxxxx'

    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id='794cb163-ca1c-4fec-b7df-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        tenant='6c3f1c39-b84c-4188-b49f-xxxxxxxxx'
    )
    kv_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    # You MIGHT need to add KeyVault as a valid provider for these credentials
    # If so, this operation has to be done only once for each credentials
    resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.KeyVault')

    # Create Resource group
    print('\nCreate Resource Group')
    resource_group_params = {'location': WEST_US}
    print_item(resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME, resource_group_params))

    # Create a vault
    print('\nCreate a vault')
    vault = kv_client.vaults.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        KV_NAME,
        {
            'location': WEST_US,
            'properties': {
                'sku': {
                    'name': 'standard'
                },
                'tenant_id': '6c3f1c39-b84c-4188-b49f-xxxxxxxxx',
                'access_policies': [{
                    'tenant_id': '6c3f1c39-b84c-4188-b49f-xxxxxxxx',
                    'object_id': OBJECT_ID,
                    'permissions': {
                        'keys': ['all'],
                        'secrets': ['all']
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    )
    print_item(vault)

    # List the Key vaults
    print('\nList KeyVault')
    for vault in kv_client.vaults.list():
        print_item(vault)

    # Delete Resource group and everything in it
    # print('\nDelete Resource Group')
    # delete_async_operation = resource_client.resource_groups.delete(GROUP_NAME)
    # delete_async_operation.wait()
    # print("\nDeleted: {}".format(GROUP_NAME))


def print_item(group):
    """Print an instance."""
    print("\tName: {}".format(group.name))
    print("\tId: {}".format(group.id))
    print("\tLocation: {}".format(group.location))
    print("\tTags: {}".format(group.tags))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_example()
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where **key vault** created successfully under new resource group with Location as `Germany West Central` like below:

[image]

When I checked **Access policies** of this key vault, it has application added to it with permissions as below:

[image]

Comment: thank you for taking your time for my issue. I'm still stuck at the step:  Go to Azure Portal -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Contributor, In the roles tab I searched for `Contributor` within the built-in roles, but I don't see it. I found `Key Vault Contributor` and `Key Vault Secrets Officer`. I tried assignment of both roles to my Service Principal, but still have the same issue

Comment: You need to assign `Contributor` role to service principal under subscription. Usually, it can be found at the beginning itself like [this](https://i.imgur.com/vqMALRs.png). If you still cannot find it, could you include the screenshot of **roles** you have and what screen you are getting by editing your question?

Comment: Meanwhile I assigned the role, see edit. When running your code with my credentials I'm getting `  File "/Users/deniz/Dev/az-storage/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 92, in on_request
    self._token = self._credential.get_token(*self._scopes)
AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token'`.

Comment: That error depends on what versions of packages and modules you are using. If you are using `azure.identity` package, try cloning this [GitHub sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/tree/main/samples/keyvault)

Comment: Thanks for your hint, got it running with the last  repo you posted